# How to check socket connection is available or not in nodejs stompit

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

I was use stompit module for connect activeMQ in node js.

My problem : Unable to identify whether broker is connected or not in stompit.ConnectFailover

Here is my code:

```
var stompit = require('stompit')

var connectionManager = new stompit.ConnectFailover();

connectionManager.addServer({
  'host': 'localhost',
  'port': 61623,
  'connectHeaders':{
    ...
  }
});

var channel = new stompit.Channel(connectionManager);

var subscribeHeaders = {
    'destination': '/queue/test',
    'ack': 'client'
};


channel.subscribe(subscribeHeaders, function(error, message){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }  
});

//send . But not throw error , even broker is not started
//always trying to reconnect
sendDlQ(subscribeHeaders, 'Hello');


function sendDlQ(header, body){
     channel.send(header, body);
}
```

Whenever call send method , always success.
Even broker is not started.

**How to identify broker is connected or not before send ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already connection option available from Channel.js from stompit library

check `if(channel._client != null && !channel._closed)`